# Passing a JSON document in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pass a policy document to be encoded into base64.

The policy document is located at `~/policy_document`

```
>>> policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)
```

What do I need to do here to get `policy_document` to pass it to base64? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# First open the file
# Then read the entire contents into memory
>>> policy_document = open("/absolute/path/to/policy_document", "r").read()

# Then base64 encode the contents.
>>> policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)

# If you are using Python 2.7 you can use the with statement
# to ensure files are cleaned up
# (See @Niklas' comment)
>>> with open("/absolute/path/to/policy_document", "r") as fp:
...     policy_document = fp.read()
...      policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)
# fp will be properly closed
```

---

Alternately, if you need it to be from the *current* user's home folder you could add a call to [`os.path.expanduser("~/policy_document")`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: you might also want to close the file afterwards or use a `with open(...) as file:` statement in Python 2.7, depending on whether or not the script terminates right after the operations.

Comment: I removed the `-1` from the `read()` call as it adds nothing and just clutters it (from `help(file)`: "If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.").

Comment: @Niklas: not `as file`, please; `file` is a builtin.

Comment: @Chris: yes, you are right. I normally call the variable just `f`, but I thought it might be cleaner to give it a real name here. Seems this was not a good idea..

Comment: @Sean: are you particularly attached to using `file.read(-1)` rather than `file.read()`? They're entirely equivalent but I know which I prefer, and it's not the longer one.

Comment: @Chris - I prefer `.read(-1)` because it reminds me that I'm really loading the *whole* file into memory ... and if I balk at that idea I re-write to deal with large files. (`.read()`, for some reason *to my mind* doesn't carry that explicit warning "you are reading the whole file").  But I've updated the examples to use the shorter, more normal `.read()` :-)

Comment: @Sean: hmm. I've never had any trouble with remembering that `file.read()` reads the whole thing. But then I find it's quite rare that I actually use `file.read()`; iterating over the `file` object is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
policy = base64.b64encode(json.JSONEncoder().encode({dict})
```